# Sending emails from local sever by mail() function

Tags: php, email, xampp, php-ini

I am trying to send email from a xampp server with below php code. Php code seems to work fine as it gives all success and error messages but I am not recieving any mails on email I provide in form.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$email  = $_POST['email'];
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {// Validate email address
    $message =  "Invalid email address please type a valid email!";
}
else
{
    $query = $con->prepare("SELECT username FROM members where email=:email");
    $query->execute(array(':email'=>$email));
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($query->rowCount() == 1) {
        $encrypt = md5(1290*3+$row['username']);
        $message = "Your password reset link has been send to your e-mail address. Check your mail and click on the link therein.";
        $to=$email;
        $subject="Password Recovery";
        $from = 'mydemo.com';
        $body='Hi, <br/> <br/>Your username is '.$row['username'].' <br><br>Click here to reset your password http://localhost/mydemo/reset.php?encrypt='.$encrypt.'   <br/> <br/>--<br>';
        $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

        mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);

    }
    else
    {
        $message = "Account not found please enter email you provided during sign up!";
    }
    }
    }

<form action="" method="POST">
<legend>Forgot your password!</legend>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required" maxlength="35" placeholder="Enter your email here..."/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<div id="message"><?php echo $message; ?></div>
```

I have also made following changes to `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` and `c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini` actually I had two php.ini development and production. I made changes to `php-ini-development`

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = gmailid@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=gmailid@gmail.com
auth_password=gmailpassword
force_sender=my-gmailid@gmail.com
```

Comment: Have you checked in your email if it's in the spam folder? (emails sent from the php `mail()` function often get marked as spam - if you want to avoid this, check out SendGrid or Mailgun)

Comment: take a look at this post http://php.codeindepth.com/php-sending-mail/

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)) {
   /*Here you can log error*/
   print_r(error_get_last());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't know if it works fine because you don't check result of function mail(). Add one if

```
if (false === mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)) {
   $message = "Mail was not sent";
}
```

From manual:

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.